# ReferenceError: 'x' is not defined - asp.net mvc partial view and jQuery/JavaScript - passing the entire model to an action method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In a partial view, I attempt to pass an ENTIRE model to the post to the controller's action method but get an error. (However, I can pass a single property of the model just fine - see at the bottom):

```
$.post("/BlogPublished/SetModelSessionVar", @Model);
```

I get an error:

```
 GnbgWebClient is not defined ReferenceError: GnbgWebClient is not defined
```

as seen in the console.

I have a break point. I can see the model and the values fine in the post to the controller's action method.

[image]

---

Note: If I surround the @Model WITH single quotes such as:

```
    $.post("/BlogPublished/SetModelSessionVar", '@Model');
```

The post is made but the model received does not contain any values. It is initialized.

[image]

---

Note: I tried with using the argument name and WITHOUT the single quotes:

```
  $.post("/BlogPublished/SetModelSessionVar", { likeOrDislikeVM: @Model } );
```

but get the same error - GnbgWebClient is not defined ReferenceError: GnbgWebClient is not defined

Same criteria, a different version of the post but same result:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
        data: { likeOrDislikeVM: @Model},
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to SetModelSessionVar! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    })
```

---

Note: I tried with using the argument name and WITH the single quotes:

```
  $.post("/BlogPublished/SetModelSessionVar", { likeOrDislikeVM: '@Model' } );
```

The post is made but the model just has NULL. Not the values I am passing in.

[image]

Same criteria, a different version of the post but same result:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
        data: { likeOrDislikeVM: '@Model'},
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to SetModelSessionVar! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    })
```

---

Now I create a JavaScript variable from the input model and the structure the same as the input model.

I get a similar reference error:

```
 holdLikeOrDislikeVM is not defined ReferenceError: holdLikeOrDislikeVM is not defined
```

as seen in the console.

[image]

I have a break point. I can see the JavaScript variable and the values fine in the post to the controller's action method.

[image]

---

Now just passing a SINGLE property of the Model using the argument name and WITHOUT the single quotes:

```
  $.post("/BlogPublished/SetCountSessionVar", { value: @Model.LikeCount});
```

and it gets to the controller and shows the correct value.

[image]

Here, I am just passing a single property of the Model using the argument name and WITH the single quotes:

```
  $.post("/BlogPublished/SetCountSessionVar", { value: '@Model.LikeCount'});
```

and it gets to the controller and shows the correct value.

[image]

---

The partial view code:

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.LikeOrDislikeVM

<style>
.fa {
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

    .fa:hover {
        color: blue;
    }

/* I added. */
.my-size {
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
<p><span class="blogLike my-size fa fa-thumbs-up"></span><span class="my-size"> : @Model.LikeCount</span> <span class="my-size"> | </span><span class="blogDisLike my-size fa fa-thumbs-down"></span><span class="my-size"> : @Model.DisLikeCount</span></p>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('here at ready');

    const False = false, True = true;

    // Set the disabled attributes.
    SetLike(@Model.LikeDisabled);
    SetDisLike(@Model.DisLikeDisabled);

    $.post("/BlogPublished/SetModelSessionVar", @Model);

    function SetLike(disabledSwitch) {
        console.log('here at SetLike');
        $(".blogLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        if (disabledSwitch == true )
        {
            $(".blogLike").css('color', 'green');
        }
    }

    function SetDisLike(disabledSwitch) {
        console.log('here at SetDisLike');
        $(".blogDisLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        if (disabledSwitch == true)
        {
            $(".blogDisLike").css('color', 'green');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

The controller action method:

```
    public void SetModelSessionVar(LikeOrDislikeVM likeOrDislikeVM)
    {
        // Sets a model session variable according to the argument passed in.

        Session["likeOrDislikeVM"] = likeOrDislikeVM;
    }
```

Comment: Please use HttpPost attribute on your action SetModelSessionVar of controller. Rest other code looks good to me. I think, this may reason. and if this is still not working then please try to post your data from button click event instead of ready.

Comment: I added the HttpPost per my other reply. No change, same result. I need it in the ready so as to save the model in a session variable so that when the thumb is clicked the session variable can be used and passed to the action method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize the model. You can see the gibberish being created on the page if you view source. You will see that the c# type name is being used.

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly pass @Model as is. You should surround it with single quotes.

Few steps that could work:

1. Try adding HttpPost to the action.
2. Always easiest and flexible way of posting data to controller would be using AJAX, as it provides various options while post.

Comment: Naveen...I already surrounded it with single quotes as the screen shot above shows but I get an empty model. Per your suggestion, I added the HttpPost. No change, same result.  $.post is a shorthand for $.ajax and works elsewhere in my app doing the same thing to pass and set a session variable. The only difference is that in the method that works, I set an integer where as in this method I am passing and setting a model